# Que functions and execute after animation is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am using SignalR to update my web app in real time based on operations taking place on the server. Right now I am incrementing a counter eachtime a record is saved in the database. I want the span holding the counter number to fade out, change, then fade back in. The only issue here is the method can be called several times within the time it takes to complete a fade out. My current code looks like this.

```
var todaysRequests = "";

var todayElement = $('#todays-requests');

//check if element is currently being animated, if so, just change the span text. If not then 
//initiate the animation then change the span text
if ($(todayElement).is(':animated')) {
    todaysRequests = parseInt($('#todays-requests').text());
    todaysRequests++;
    $(todayElement).text(todaysRequests.toString());
} else {
    $(todayElement).fadeOut(300, function () {
        //at this point its possible another call was made to this method and the counter was 
        //incremented. We need to get the counter number again just incase it has been incremented
        //then we can actually increment it.
        todaysRequests = parseInt($('#todays-requests').text());
        todaysRequests++;
        $(todayElement).text(todaysRequests.toString());
        $(todayElement).fadeIn(300);
    });
}
```

The problem is there's no way to persist data in between calls to the above function. I thought about using local storage to store an integer that gets incremented each time this function gets run while the span is still being animated, then in the animation finish check local storage and adjust the counter. This could work but it seems like too much work. There has to be a more elegant solution. Right now it doesn't look so bad but if more than one call to the function is made you can see the span incrementing as it is fading out.

**Update**
Checking into jquery.queue(). It looks like you can que functions to an element to be called after something else happens. I'm not 100% sure how to que them and then have them execute only after animation is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var todayElement = $("#todays-requests")
, data = 0;

$.when(todayElement.queue("fx", function () {
    todayElement.fadeOut(300, function () {
        todayElement.text(data)
    }).fadeIn(300)
}).dequeue("fx"))        
    .promise("fx", todayElement)
    .done(function (el) {
    console.log(data + " tasks complete"
                , "queue length: " + el.queue("fx").length)
})
```

```js
var todayElement = $("#todays-requests"),
    data = 0;

var request = function (d, t) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.get("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/ca95080f6d3a7b32bb95/raw/120dec0dce825193b0551ad1fbda4b71029b336d/js.js")
            .done(function (n) {
            ++data
        })
    }, t)
};

for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    request(i, i * 275)
}

$(document).on("ajaxStop", function (e) {
    $.when(todayElement.queue("fx", function () {
        todayElement.fadeOut(300, function () {
            todayElement.text(data)
        }).fadeIn(300)
    }).dequeue("fx"))        
        .promise("fx", todayElement)
        .done(function (el) {
        console.log(data + " tasks complete"
                    , "queue length: " + el.queue("fx").length)
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="todays-requests"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer and example! It works. Now I have to figure out exactly how it works.

Comment: @Adrian You are welcome:) See http://api.jquery.com/queue/ , http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/ , http://api.jquery.com/promise/ , http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/